Calculating p-values
My code in Stata below aggregates the estimates from individual event-study regressions, to calculate the average effect of all treatment. The average effect is conceptually equivalent to the output of a stacked regression, but with the advantage of being able to use custom weights to calculate more efficient averages. However, the code only gives me a coefficient and the standard error for each of my outcomes. I'd also like to find the p-values to determine statistical significance. Since I do not want to significantly rehaul my code, how can I do this?
Alternately, how can I manually calculate the p-value given a coefficient and the standard error?

////////////////////////////////////////////////
////                                        ////
////    PART 1. Define regression program   ////
////                                        ////
////////////////////////////////////////////////


capture program drop runEventStudies

program define runEventStudies
    
    args data yList name
    

    use "${outdir}\\`data'.dta", clear
    

    * group indicator. So it's 1 both before and after the event - Luca mail 09/06
    bysort state: egen treated = max(stepone)
    
    egen eventBlock = group(Treated_State adopt_week)
    
    qui gen post = weeknum > adopt_week //should turn on for the controls based on the state 
    *for which the reg is run - aka eventblock
    *qui gen event = weeknum == adopt_week
    *qui gen treated_event = treated * event 
    qui gen treated_post = treated * post
    qui gen treated_trend = weeknum * treated
    
    
    qui sum eventBlock
    local N = r(max)
 
    disp "TOTAL: `N'"
 
 
    * Run regressions   - include test rates
    foreach y of local yList {
        
        disp "`y'"
        
        forvalues i = 1/`N' {
            disp "`i'"
            
            * Balanced T, with FEs to control for week 
            areg `y' post treated_post tested i.weeknum if eventBlock == `i'  ///
                    ,absorb(state)  //mine is not a balanced panel - restrict analysis to make it balanced
            local b_`y'_`i'_b = _b[treated_post]
            local se_`y'_`i'_b = _se[treated_post]  
            
            
            * Adding linear, group-specific trend           
            qui areg `y' weeknum treated_trend post treated_post tested i.weeknum ///
                if eventBlock == `i',absorb(state)
            local b_`y'_`i'_b_trend = _b[treated_post]
            local se_`y'_`i'_b_trend = _se[treated_post]
            
            

            
            }
        }
    
            

*** Step 2: Construct a dataset saving all coefficients and SEs

*keep Treated_State adopt_week eventBlock cem_varlist 
    qui duplicates drop

    foreach suff in b b_trend {
        
        foreach y of local yList {
                
            qui gen b_`y'_`suff' = ""
            qui gen se_`y'_`suff' = ""
        
            forvalues i = 1/`N' {
                
                qui replace b_`y'_`suff' = "`b_`y'_`i'_`suff''" if eventBlock == `i'
                qui replace se_`y'_`suff' = "`se_`y'_`i'_`suff''" if eventBlock == `i'
                
                }
            
            qui destring b_`y'_`suff', replace
            qui destring se_`y'_`suff', replace
            
            }
        }
 
    drop eventBlock
    
        * Save the data
        foreach x in Treated_State {
        encode `x', gen(temp)
        drop `x'
        rename temp `x'
        }
 
    * save
    order state weeknum cem_varlist 
    sort state weeknum
    save "${coeffdir}\coefficients_`name'.dta", replace

    
end



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////                                                        ////////////
////////////            PART 2. Run the event studies               ////////////
////////////                                                        ////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


* Acquired  
runEventStudies  "1matched_cohort"                                      /// Data
                `"confirmed_1 recovered_1 deceased_1"'                  /// yList
                 "one"                                                  /// name


    
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////                                                        ////////////
////////////            PART 3. Calculate averages                  ////////////
////////////                                                        ////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


* Uses Inverse variance average: these weights give the smallest SE of the sum of the vars



local oneVars   "confirmed_1 recovered_1 deceased_1"
local twoVars   "confirmed_2 recovered_2 deceased_2"
local threeVars "confirmed_3 recovered_3 deceased_3"
local fourVars  "confirmed_4 recovered_4 deceased_4"

local sets `" "" "_trend" "'


foreach set of local sets {
    
    
    * open file, write header
    file open EScoeff using "${paperdir}\Tables\EScoeff`set'.csv", write replace


    file write EScoeff "Variable,All states,Early adopters,Late adopters" _n
                
        foreach sample in one two three four {
        
        use "${coeffdir}\coefficients_`sample'.dta", replace

        * Average effect of all states
        foreach var of local `sample'Vars {
            
            * ALL
            qui egen wavg_`var' = wtmean(b_`var'_b`set') ///
                if treated == 1, weight(1/(se_`var'_b`set'^2))
            qui egen wvar_`var' = mean(1/(se_`var'_b`set'^2)) /// SE command
                if treated == 1 
            qui replace wvar_`var' = sqrt(1/wvar_`var') ///follows from 206
            
            * record values
            sum wavg_`var'
            local avgAllStates : display %4.2f r(mean)
            drop wavg_`var'
            sum wvar_`var'
            local sdAllStates : display %4.2f r(mean)
            drop wvar_`var'     

                        
                    
/*
            file write testtable "`var',`avgAllStates'" _n  
            file write testtable `",="(`sdAllStates')""' _n  
            */

            file write EScoeff "`var',`avgAllStates',`avgEarlyStates',`avgLateStates'" _n  
            file write EScoeff `",="(`sdAllStates')",="(`sdEarlyStates')",="(`sdLateStates')""' _n
            
        }       
        
        }

    file close EScoeff
    
}


Data sample
input str50 state byte stepone str13 Treated_State byte(weeknum adopt_week) float(tested confirmed_1 recovered_1 deceased_1)
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 45 22    16.280634     .21531174     .21075015    .001205656
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 32 22      7.18386      .1659875      .1561607     .00080393
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 41 22    13.814168     .20439556     .19904032   .0011118283
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 44 22    15.731228     .21312033      .2083853    .001183663
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 17 22     .1847392    .008343254    .006337254   .0000580895
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 38 22     11.61945     .19399765     .18851824   .0010309094
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 29 22     5.068347     .14344008     .13148248   .0007292264
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 16 22     .1419289    .006759179    .005025698  .00004458309
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 43 22    15.157097     .21073844     .20558017   .0011626267
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 26 22    2.7848125     .11582927      .1013988   .0005929671
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 39 22    12.378263      .1976383     .19192722   .0010621055
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 23 22    1.0034382     .07272435      .0476965   .0003849923
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 11 22    .04245099    .001358888    .000448341   7.53012e-06
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 31 22     6.606687       .159154     .14880905   .0007728533
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 47 22     17.28098      .2176378     .21473382    .001243187
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 34 22     8.671193     .17866656     .16996786     .00088963
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  4 22            0 .000017450755  7.171544e-07  7.171544e-07
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 13 22    .06862139    .003441026   .0015243116  .00002067795
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 21 22     .4104603    .036436457     .02434966  .00022243737
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 22 22    .58980757     .05235824    .033925343   .0002959457
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 20 22     .3337463    .024219856    .015814569  .00016518455
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 48 22     5.016259     .06231139     .06166022   .0003585772
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 28 22     4.260896     .13483803     .12253084   .0007003012
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 10 22   .030944014    .000708907   .0003206875  5.259132e-06
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  9 22   .023821475     .00044607  .00013972557 3.5857715e-06
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  5 22  .0021611445 .000034781988  8.964429e-06    8.3668e-07
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 37 22    10.968039       .190893      .1850546   .0010001912
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  3 22            0   3.34672e-06             0             0
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 15 22    .11010375    .005678189   .0037403186   .0000334672
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  8 22    .01659794   .0003028782  .00005581851 1.7928858e-06
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  6 22   .006518694  .00005976286  .00002402467    8.3668e-07
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 46 22    16.790081     .21676815      .2128226   .0012233458
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 25 22    2.1707711     .10481963     .08708943   .0005343995
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 40 22     13.10717     .20105493     .19557564   .0010884013
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 18 22     .2263394    .010706636    .007791762  .00008283133
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 12 22    .04013124   .0024207544   .0007249235 .000011235418
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 42 22    14.507592     .20766734      .2023336   .0011390802
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 19 22    .27508557    .015854968     .01087182  .00012155766
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 30 22     5.962443     .15187284     .14039527   .0007506215
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 33 22     7.866549      .1729872      .1631078   .0008461226
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 35 22     9.480743     .18312895      .1762636      .0009274
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 24 22    1.5934727     .09181153     .06732514  .00046399885
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 36 22    10.247828     .18750395      .1810866    .000966963
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar"  7 22    .01026487   .0001143861 .000035618665   1.67336e-06
"Bihar"                       1 "Bihar" 27 22     3.595409     .12605326       .112047    .000643885
"Bihar"                       0 "Bihar" 14 22    .08867207   .0045832135   .0023129422 .000027012813
"Tamil Nadu"                  0 "Bihar" 31 22    10.399572      .8328966      .7599111     .01310164
"Kerala"                      0 "Bihar" 32 22    10.481126      .8627852      .5889338   .0029799694
"DNHnDD"                      0 "Bihar" 31 22     7.098346      .3239088      .3102786  .00020855057
"DNHnDD"                      0 "Bihar" 45 22            0      .3512737      .3472516  .00020855057
"Goa"                         0 "Bihar"  5 22   .006474954   .0004545455  9.276439e-06             0
"Andhra Pradesh"              0 "Bihar" 29 22    10.027867     1.2246617     1.0736066     .01045064
"Telangana"                   0 "Bihar" 19 22     .5291103     .10167153     .06675328   .0010090581
"Andhra Pradesh"              0 "Bihar" 19 22    2.2918196     .06419585      .0333213    .000790049
"Tripura"                     0 "Bihar" 28 22     8.414711     .49370885      .3015925     .00518895
"Himachal Pradesh"            0 "Bihar"  2 22            0 3.9138945e-06             0             0
"Uttar Pradesh"               0 "Bihar" 44 22    10.940186      .2620493     .25282785    .003746318
"Kerala"                      0 "Bihar" 29 22     7.141237      .4114534     .28997296   .0016374175
"Andhra Pradesh"              0 "Bihar" 14 22      .922762     .00960916    .005391099   .0001471767
"DNHnDD"                      0 "Bihar" 28 22     6.201341     .29074928     .26459107  .00020855057
"DNHnDD"                      0 "Bihar" 19 22     3.864889     .05648741     .03478326   .0001489647
"Gujarat"                     0 "Bihar"  8 22    .08439687    .005654902   .0006937201   .0002678992
"DNHnDD"                      0 "Bihar" 26 22     5.691241     .25045434     .21994637  .00020855057
"Tamil Nadu"                  0 "Bihar" 17 22    1.5489976     .11930643     .06695649   .0015883292
"Himachal Pradesh"            0 "Bihar" 12 22     .4074325    .003340509   .0009080234   .0000665362
"Tripura"                     0 "Bihar" 13 22     .7343115     .01232107    .004330089             0



This can't be answered as a programming problem as (1) it doesn't explain how the desired results are to be calculated and (2) it isn't a minimal reproducible problem in any case.

Cross-posted at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/651519/calculating-p-values where it is judged off-topic for complementary reasons.

Hi @NickCox. Would providing a sample of my data help answer this question? I'm not sure I fully understand your comment

I don't follow what is unclear about my comment. You're expecting us not only to read and then amend ode we can't reproduce but also to know how P-values can be computed given "individual event-study regressions" you don't document.  That may make sense to someone, but not to me; hence my vote to close.  SO isn't a help line, but a forum for fully documented and highly focused problems.

@NickCox. Thanks. While I understand that SO is not a help line, as a novice on this forum, all it needed was the clarification you now provided. I have added the code for the individual event-study regressions and sample data. I'd greatly appreciate it if you can help me

You can combine estimates from separate regression models like this:
// Load the 'auto' dataset into memory, clearing any existing data in memory
sysuse auto, clear

// Create a new variable 'terc_mpg' that divides 'mpg' (miles per gallon) into tertiles (3 equal groups)
xtile terc_mpg = mpg, nq(3)

// Run a regression analysis of 'price' on the tertile groups of 'mpg' and 'weight' for domestic cars (foreign == 0)
reg price i.terc_mpg c.weight if foreign == 0

// Store the estimates from the previous regression for later comparison, labeled as 'domestic'
estimates store domestic

// Repeat the regression analysis for foreign cars (foreign == 1)
reg price i.terc_mpg c.weight if foreign == 1

// Store these estimates as well, labeled as 'foreign'
estimates store foreign

// Perform a seemingly unrelated estimation (suest) to compare the 'domestic' and 'foreign' models
suest domestic foreign, coefl

// Use the 'lincom' command to compute a linear combination of coefficients, 
// specifically a weighted average of the 'weight' variable's coefficients from the two models
lincom (_b[domestic_mean:weight]*0.75 + _b[foreign_mean:weight]*0.25)

Unfortunately, this won't work with areg, so you must use reg (or something similar) for your DID.
If you insist on doing this manually, use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance#Covariance_of_linear_combinations.
